# how to use a multiphrasequery?

Tags: java, lucene

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiPhraseQuery.html

for the example "Microsoft app*", he says use `IndexReader.term()` but that returns `TermEnum`,  how do I put it in `MultiPhraseQueryParser` ?

Edit :

Or someone tell me how do I do a search on *Microsoft app** in a better way over a 7.5 GB index!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate on TermEnum to get the terms. You can iterate on the TermEnum to get terms starting with "app" as follows.

```
    TermEnum te = reader.terms(new Term("field", "app"));
    List<Term> termList = new LinkedList<Term>();       
    while(te.next()) {
        Term t = te.term();
        if (!t.field().equals("field") || !t.text().startsWith("app")) {
            break;
        }
        termList.add(t);
    }
    Term[] terms = termList.toArray(new Term[0]);
```

Comment: Oh my God!!! I've 427800 docs!!! iterating over a 7.5 GB index would make it go crazy isn't it ?!!!!

Comment: Since you are iterating only on small subset of terms, it is quite fast. Try it out.