# Lucene phrase match with a wildcard at the end

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to make a predictive text search that allows a user to start typing, and results from their text come through as results

E.g. with "ca" they can get 
"cat in the hat", 
"my calculus is cool"
"cat dog mouse"

However, if a person continues to type with spaces, I want the whole phrase to be considered as one term

E.g. "cat i" should find 
"cat in the hat"

but NOT "[cat] dog mouse" nor "my calculus [i]s cool"

This is my current code, however it does not seem to be working as I'd hoped:

```
val mySort = new Sort(SortField.FIELD_SCORE, new SortField("popularity", SortField.Type.INT, true))
val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43)

val parser: QueryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "title", analyzer)
val query = parser.parse(queryString+"*")
val titleQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(query)
titleQuery.setBoost(2)

val synopsisQuery = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "synopsis", analyzer).parse(queryString)
val summaryQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(synopsisQuery)

val finalQuery = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(0)
finalQuery.add(titleQuery)
finalQuery.add(summaryQuery)

val collector = TopFieldCollector.create(mySort,Limit,false,true,true,false)

searcher.search(finalQuery, collector)

collector.topDocs().scoreDocs
```

Answer (score 4):

There are basically two ways to achieve this.

The *old way*, is to construct a `MultiPhraseQuery` manually - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5075429/3764814) for details.

The *new* way is simpler though: construct a [`SpanNearQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html). Use the following parameters: `inOrder = true` and `slop = 0` to get an equivalent of `PhraseQuery`.

Each clause in the `SpanNearQuery` should be a [`SpanTermQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanTermQuery.html) **except** the last one. These should be the full terms contained in your phrase.

The last clause should be a [`SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<PrefixQuery>`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.html), wrapping a [`PrefixQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html). Use the last term of your phrase as the prefix value.

To sum up, for `cat i`:

```
SpanNearQuery [inOrder = true, slop = 0]
 |
 +-- SpanTermQuery [term = "cat"]
 |
 +-- SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<PrefixQuery>
      |
      +-- Prefixquery [prefix = "i"]
```

Comment: Thanks - I've been playing with ComplexPhrase, and seem to have something working like like "cat i*".  Would you say that is better or using SpanNear?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `ComplexPhraseQuery` (I don't use Lucene's query parsers much). I took a quick look at the source code, and this query gets basically rewritten to a `SpanNearQuery` in your case. So it's the same approach in the end, you can use `ComplexPhraseQuery` if it's easier for you to construct.